# Java - Iterate over a custom alphabet

Tags: java, loops

After searching the web and this site I am unable to find an exact solution to my problem.

I want to generate a list starting with 'a' and iterate in the following fashion: a, b, c, aa, ab, ac, ba, bb, bc, ca, cb, cc, aaa...

I would like to specify 2 variables, a string of characters that will be iterated through and an integer showing the max length/depth of the results. I would like the ability to change the string of characters to anything I like and any length.

```
String alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
int depth = 6;
```

I hope that I am being specific enough for answers. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments! I greatly appreciate the help! I'm new in recursion--hence the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you need. If you want to brute force.

```
 public static void combin(String input,StringBuffer output,int depth){
      if (depth == 0) {
            System.out.println(output);
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
                output.append(input.charAt(i));
                combin(input, output,depth - 1);
                output.deleteCharAt(output.length() - 1);
            }
        }    
 }
```

Comment: This was the easiest to implement, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Imagine each character in the max length strength being a 'tumbler', like the tumblers of an analog counter (back before we used computers!). The tumbler has on its sides -1, 0, 1, 2... and also has the property that while it starts at -1 (0 for the rightmost one), when it ticks over from MAX it goes to 0 instead of to -1, and it also ticks the tumbler one left of it once (which can also tick the tumbler left of it once if it also overflows, and so on)

Now, we have an algorithm like this:

1) Initialize a list of integers: -1, -1, -1... 0, `depth` in total. Refer to these as the counters.

2) Increment the rightmost counter.

3) Now for the tricky part. Keep an integer variable indicating which counter we are currently working on, call it `idx = depth-1`. If the counter we incremented overflowed, then instead of skipping this step, decrement `idx` by `1` and tick the newly pointed to counter by 1. In a loop, check if that overflowed too, if so looping it around and moving up one counter, etc etc until we either move `idx` so left it goes past 0 (if so, return, we have printed out all combinations and looped around) or do not overflow a counter.

4) print out the string corresponding to the indices of your list into `alpha` (if -1, add nothing).

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion to solve this easily:

```
List<String> product(String chars, int length) {
    List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
    res.add("");
    if (length > 0) {
        for (c : chars) {
            res.addAll(product(chars, length - 1) + c);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

For your given string and length, this list will be *very* big (~2 billion entries).

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is recursion! This is one of my favorite topics in computer science, so check it out here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29 The function creates a loop by calling itself.

```
String recurse(String dataSet, String current, int limit) {
    // iterate through each character to add to the word
    for (int i=0; i<dataSet.length(); i++) {
        // print the current character along with the total behind it
        System.out.println(current + dataSet.charAt(i));
        // stop if you reach the length limit
        if (current.length() < limit) {
            // start again with each set of data
            recurse(current + dataSet.charAt(i));
        }
    }
}

recurse("abc", "", 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously using [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) we are able to write this in a fairly short form. The function takes in some collection (I have used a set in this example) as opposed to creating multiple object to reduce memory overhead.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<String> set = new TreeSet<String>();
    GenerateUniques(set, "", "abcdefghijklmn", 6);
    System.out.println(set.size());
}

private static void GenerateUniques(Collection<String> coll, String prefix, String chars, int depth) {
    if (depth-- == 0) return;
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length(); i++) {
        String str = prefix + chars.charAt(i);
        coll.add(str);
        GenerateUniques(coll, str, chars, depth);
    }
}
```